# Discord.py | Can a bot generate a Server Invite Link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if it is possible for a bot, to generate a Discord Server Link. Basically after I **UnBan** a discord user I want the bot to invite him back. I have not tried anything yet. I searched on google but could not find anything.

(Notes: I'm using Discord.py in it's latest version.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your **Unban** command to create a discord invite for that specific **text channel** and then send it to the user being unbanned:

```
# This will create the invite
invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
# This will send the user the invite via Private Message
# You will need to have fetched the user previously
await user.send(invite)
```

You might also want to check the [**official discord.py documentation**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to check the optional parameters that you can pass to the `create_invite()` method.

[Reference of method `create_invite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_invite)

Comment: Yeah, I did that but it seems it does not send the invite link. It does not seem to be working at all. The unban command works perfectly fine and the embed too. but when it comes to the invite it does not work at all. Note: I'm unbanning with an ID, could that be the issue?

Comment: As I stated, you will need to fetch the user first, it you have his ID you can use [fetch_user()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user), or use [get_user()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) if that user is already in cached.

Comment: Oh so basically I'm gonna do 
`invite = await ctx.message.channel.create_invite()
 await fetch_user(user_id)
 await user.send(invite)`
?

Comment: Yes but your syntax is wrong. After fetching the user save it to a variable user then do `await user.send(invite)`.  This is because fetch_user returns the user and does not save into the cache but to a variable. EDIT: Also, I think you have to call fetch_user on a bot object, `await bot.fetch_user()` but I'm not entirely sure

Comment: I did everything but I need to define `user_id` which is inside of `await fetch_user(user_id)`. What am I gonna define it?