# Discord.js generate a Channel Invite

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to generate a discord channel invite that my bot sends to a user which only he can use, so an one time use. But I'm not getting it and I need some help.

This is my code:

```
if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
  await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(
       user.id);
  if(array.length >= 1){
    if(message.member.roles.cache.has('529770658914369537')){
      const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'Gaming Lounge')
      let invite = channel.createInvite({
        maxAge: 0, 
        maxUses: 1 
      }).catch(console.error);
      console.log(`Here is your Invite: ${invite}`);
      client.users.cache.get(array[0]).send(
        `Here is your Invite: ${invite}`);
      array.splice(0, 1);
      console.log(array);
      reaction.users.remove(user);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? You are going to need to be more specific than "not getting it"

Comment: well i dont know how to generate a Discord Invite

Comment: so i need a invite link that the user can use one time and thats it

Comment: if i use the code from above i get this message sent: Here is your Invite: [object Promise]

Comment: You are missing an `await`

Comment: it worked with the await but now i have the problem that the max uses is not working, meaning i can use the invite as often that i want. but i need a one time use invite

Comment: Maybe ask that as a separate question

Comment: ok and how shoul i do that cause i dont know how you mean it

Answer (score 1):

**discord.js:**

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new discord.Client();

const prefix = '&';

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am awake');
});

bot.on('message', message => { 
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) 
    return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const replyWithInvite = async (message) => {
        let invite = await message.channel.createInvite(
            {
                maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000, // maximum time for the invite, in milliseconds
                maxUses: 1 // maximum times it can be used
            },
            `Requested with command by ${message.author.tag}`
        )
        .catch(console.log);

        message.author.send(invite ? `Here's your invite: ${invite}` : "There has been an error during the creation of the invite.");
    }

    if (command === 'invite') {
        
        replyWithInvite(message);
    }
});

bot.login('<Your-Login-Token>');
```

In my case I use the prefix "&invite", but you can change that however you see fit.

---

**discord.py:**

this thread might help?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65770179/14476782

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<message>.channel.createInvite()` method

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'Gaming Lounge')
const channelInvite = await channel.createInvite({ maxAge: 60000, maxUses: 1 }).catch(e => console.log(e));
message.author.send(channelInvite ? channelInvite : 'Oops something went wrong').catch(e => console.log(e)); // incase the user dms are blocked
```

Comment: ok it works that it sends the discord invite but the maxuses doesnt work, so i sent the invite to couple people and and it worked for all. but i need it to only work one time and then the invite should be invalid